# Cinnamon randomly loses theming

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

From time to time (quite randomly), Nemo on my Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon starts looking like this
[image]

When usually it looks like this: [image]

Restarting Cinnamon (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>) doesn't help, I need to log out, and then log on.

Can someone tell me,

- (I guess, that something with [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) had crashed. `dmesg` doesn't show anything.) how to diagnose, what really happened? (*update: it seems it is  `gnome-settings-daemon` crash*)
- how to restore the normal theme without logging off (which requires closing all programs)?
- how to minimize frequency of such things?

---

Suspicious entries in `xsession-errors.lob`

```
[0x7f9590006068] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)
[0x7f9590006068] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7f9590006068] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1108 ms)
[0x7f9590006068] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

(...)

```
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] Missing reference picture
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] concealing 1620 DC, 1620 AC, 1620 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] Missing reference picture
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] Missing reference picture
[h264 @ 0x7f95790fc160] Missing reference picture
```

(...)

```
No such schema 'com.canonical.unity-greeter'
```

Suspicious entries in syslog:

```
Jun 13 01:03:45 adam-N56VZ kernel: [49764.694213] gnome-settings-[4198]: segfault at 188b2 ip 00007f2e46acf0a6 sp 00007fff8acb45d0 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.600.0[7f2e46a8c000+7c000]
Jun 13 01:03:52 adam-N56VZ gnome-session[4098]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-settings-daemon.desktop' killed by signal 11
```

(...)

```
Jun 13 01:40:59 adam-N56VZ laptop-mode: Warning: Configuration file /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/board-specific/*.conf is not readable, skipping.
```

---

Update:

It seems, that the this behavior can be reproduced by killing `gnome-settings-daemon`. The question remains on how to restore it? Simply running it as user or root doesn't change anything, even with restarting cinnamon (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

And the hardest question: how to prevent it from happening? Since it is a crash I guess I'll need to follow the procedure with filing bug report. But who's fault it is? Gnome's or Cinnamon's? Or maybe some other component is at fault here?

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/syslog` and `~/.xsession-errors` and check if you find something suspicious. If X had crashed, you wouldn't see the window at all. Also check if gnome-settings-daemon is running.

Comment: Are you using the Intel i915 driver?

Comment: @Marco Well, both the log files are sooo huge, it's really difficult to find anything in them. Espessialy in .xsession-errors (230 kB) - because there are no dates appended, so I really have no clue how old each entry is. Can you give me a hint for what I should look for?

Comment: @charlesbridge Yes, I do. `lsmod | grep i915` returns, among other entries, `i915`.

Comment: If you delete `.xsession-errors` and then log in, you know the log file contains just the log since the last log in. Furthemore, you can use `grep -v whatever` to remove noisy entries you're not interested in. Then look for *unusual* events, e.g. startup services getting killed for some reason, segmentation faults, etc. Read it bottom-up, the last entries are probably more relevant than the first ones.

Comment: @Marco Yes, I know the `grep` idiom :-). And I did read it bottom-up. I couldn't find anything really suspicious, but what I've found I put on the updated question above.

Comment: @Marco: I've found it: killing the `gnome-settings-daemon` does reproduce the problem above!! The other questions about how to restore it after it crashes and how to prevent it - remain.

Comment: Open up a terminal and try to start it manually and check if it runs or seqfaults. You can start it as `gnome-settings-daemon --debug` to obtain more information about what might go wrong.

Comment: @Marco I did it. I can't make heads or tails of it. Maybe you can help me? Here is it: http://pastebin.com/Zn3XeghF

Comment: You might run into [bug #706330](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=706330). This is a bug in the theming engine unico and can be worked around by selecting a theme which uses a different engine, e.g. *Adwaita*: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita'` and watch the log if `gnome-settings-daemon` seqfaults with this theme as well.

Comment: @Marco Thank you! Could you tell me how do I revert back to the original settings if things would turn even worse?

Comment: 1) Use a backup! A backup is an *undo button* for the entire system and reverts any setting, messed up by a user or even root. 2) For you particular case: You can obtain the current value of gtk-theme as follows: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `cinnamon-settings-daemon`/`gnome-settings-daemon` is not running.
You can put it in startup aplications to make sure it starts when you log in.

Comment: The issue I'm encountering is that `cinnamon-settings-daemon` does not exist as a command. Running it results in: `The program 'cinnamon-settings-daemon' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install cinnamon-settings-daemon` -- however when I try to install it I'm getting `cinnamon-settings-daemon is already the newest version (3.4.0-1~zesty0)`. The system was originally Ubuntu GNOME, with the `cinnamon-desktop-environment` installed on top of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

finally i got solution.

Simply open **Startup Applications** from *Control Center*, check the option **MATE Settings Daemon** or **Cinnamon Settings Daemon** (according to your Desktop Environment) and that’s it.

Now login again and problem solved.